# Sonarqube add measure on external resource

Tags: sonarqube

I have a case in which I want a plugin to save metrics on SCM Tickets.
At the moment I defined a custom SCMTicket resource (extending the Resource class) and added some metrics using the getMetrics method in a class implementing the Metrics interface.
I created a Sensor that just adds a dummy measurement on one of my metrics. My resources are not saved before saving the measurement as the saveMeasure method should do that automatically.

The problem I have is that my resources are not saved and the measures are also not saved. The metrics are saved.

Am I using a totally wrong approach or do I have to do something more to save this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a conceptual standpoint, this is a wrong approach.

The SonarQube Platform is intended to measure and track code quality. I can see an argument that tickets reflect quality, but they are not themselves code and do not have quality (or a lack thereof).

**Edit**

For aggregate values, such as the average ticket duration you mention in your comment, the best place to record them is on the project. (Which makes sense not just from an API perspective, but from a metric ownership perspective if you think about it.)

Note that once upon a time, SonarSource actually offered a JIRA plugin, but abandoned it after deciding that JIRA metrics weren't really about *code quality*.

Comment: Hmm okay I get that perspective. But say for example I want to extend the dashboard with a widget to show an average ticket duration? Is there a way to hook into sonar or would you say I should save this data externally and retrieve it with a widget in a plugin? Or is there even a better approach for this? I do think that such kind of widgets can give an extra dimension to Sonar.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think the project could be the proper domain. That just means not saving the separate metrics for every ticket but for the project in a whole. This means that you can save less details but it will probably work for the level of detail I need.